# interchanging limits for doubly indexed random sequences

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I've encountered the following problem which seems to be quite standard but for which I don't find any proper references:

Suppose that for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have a sum of random variables $S(n)= \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} X_r(n)$,  such that $X_r(n)$ and $X_s(n)$ are uncorrelated for $r \neq s$ and $S(n)$ is uniformly bounded in $L^2$. Denote by $S_k(n)$ the partial sums $\sum_{r=1}^k X_r(n)$. If we know that

1. for each $n$,
   $$S_k(n) \xrightarrow{d} N(\mu_n,\sigma^2_n), \qquad (k \to \infty),$$
   where $\xrightarrow{d}$ is convergence is distribution and $N(\mu_n,\sigma^2_n)$ denotes a Gaussian with mean $\mu_n$ and variance $\sigma^2_n$

and

2. the sequences $(\mu_n)$ and $(\sigma^2_n)$ both converge to some limits $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ (so that in particular $N(\mu_n,\sigma^2_n) \xrightarrow{d} N(\mu,\sigma^2)$,

what are sufficient conditions to conclude that $S(n) \xrightarrow{d} N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ as $n\to \infty$?

What about the more general situation where the partial sums are replaced by some doubly indexed random variables and the limiting Gaussians with some generic (continuous) random variable?

Thanks for your help!